# Scale usercontrol in wpf ? vertical and horizontal scrollbars

Tags: wpf, scale, scrollbars

I implemented a usercontrol, but i have a problem with rescaling the window. I know when i make the window smaller, everything scales, and  every textbox and label becomes also smaller. But this is not what i want, i just want that when i make the screen smaller, everything stays the same size, and that scrollbars appear ( vertical and horizontal ). How do i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption**
The behaviour you describe, is not mandatory the default layout-behaviour of WPF. It depends on the layout-controls you use. I assume, you're using a Grid with setting it's columns and rows to the Start (*)-GridLengths. This would have more or less such an effect as you describe (without scaling). Or maybe you are using a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx), this control **scales** the whole content based on the available layout size.
**Solution**
I guess that wrapping your whole content into a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx) will probably do what you desire. If not, I suggest that you post some XAML-code to show us how you have built your content.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <YourContent>

    </YourContent>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Update**
If you really **scale** your window (applying a ScaleTransformation) and you want your UserControl to be the only control within that does not scale, you have to scale your UserControl in the opposite direction as you have done it with your window. Apply a ScaleTransformation and set the scale values to 1/scale. Or try to use the ViewBox to blow up the content of your UserControl, but this will not be very exact.